# GNU GRUB version 2.02 opening when I boot laptop

Tags: grub2, initramfs

So, when I boot my laptop, it comes up with a grub interface with several options such as "Ubuntu" and "advanced options for Ubuntu" 
I'm new to Ubuntu and I cant figure out how to get back to the normal OS interface (gui) 
When I click on "Ubuntu" it takes me to an "(intitramfs)" command line 
Sorry, it may be really obvious - I'm not very experienced with CLI

Comment: I would suggest booting a 'live' system (eg. Ubuntu install media) and `fsck` (or file system check) or your file-system first. A `fsck` is read-only (it won't make changes unless errors are found; in which case they are needed) meaning no change is done unless needed. If that finds nothing, then I'd re-evaluate and consider boot-repair (given it's probably easier than commands to explore your system & boot manually).

Answer (score 1):

If your system doesn't boot up and stays stuck in initfamfs, there might be some problem in your system boot files. It can happen because of several things: wrong boot loader configuration, missing files, etc.

I suggest you to try to boot your system from an Ubuntu install disk, and then try to mount your system volume and analyse what may be wrong from there.

`boot-repair` may also help solve the problem, see: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair